# Prove $\limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_n \leq \limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n$, given $b_n = \frac{a_1+ \cdots +a_n}{n}$.

Tags: limits

[image]

I am working on this question for quite a long time. I think I will prove by contradiction, but I can not proceed. Anyone could give a hint? Thanks!

Comment: Is this homework? @vadim123 $n$, most definitively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $m$ and pick $n\geqslant m$ large. Then $$\begin{align}
  \frac{{{a_1} + {a_2} +  \cdots  + {a_m} + {a_{m + 1}} +  \cdots  + {a_n}}}{n} &\leqslant \frac{{{a_1} + {a_2} +  \cdots  + {a_m} + \left( {n - m} \right)\mathop {\sup }\limits_{k > m} {a_k}}}{n} \cr 
   &\leqslant \frac{{{a_1} + {a_2} +  \cdots  + {a_m}  }}{n} + \frac{{n - m}}{n}\mathop {\sup }\limits_{k > m} {a_k} \end{align} $$

Now hold $m$ fixed and take $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}$. You get $$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_1+\cdots+a_n}n\leqslant \sup_{k>m}a_k$$
By the same token you can show that $$\liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_1+\cdots+a_n}n\geqslant \liminf_{n\to\infty }a_n$$